# Pie Chart XAML Binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I am using MVVM and SL4. I have a collection of VoteResults that are being bound to a ItemsControl. I want a PieChart in EACH VoteResult item. A VoteResult item object properties looks like this: VotedYes 10; VotedNo 4; Abstained 2; DidntVote 6;

How can I pass these VoteItem property values to build the pie chart's series ItemSource in XAML?
Something like :

```
 <charting:Chart>
    <charting:Chart.Series>
       <charting:PieSeries>
          <charting:PieSeries.ItemsSource>
             <controls:ObjectCollection>

             </controls:ObjectCollection>
          </charting:PieSeries.ItemsSource>
       </charting:PieSeries>
    </charting:Chart.Series>
 </charting:Chart>
```

Comment: "A PieChart __in__ each.."?  Do you mean you want multiple pie charst for each?  Perhaps not that doesn't sound that useful.  What do you mean?  Do you really have multiple VoteResult items or are you refering to each property of a single VoteResult being an "item".  Please be precise, we spend a lot of our time talking to our computers in manner which out of necessity demands precision.  We therefore end up prefering to talk to each other with precision as well so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: A VoteResult (singular) contains the count of each of 4 possible responses : Yes; No ; Abstain and DidntVote. However, there can a response to multiple votes: VoterResultA, VoteResultB, VoteResultC in response to VoteA, VoteB, VoteC  etc. The ItemsControl is Binding to the COLLECTION of these responses. I need to bind the 4 possible answers (Yes,No,Abstain and DidntVote) of each VoteResult (singular) to the pie chart.

Answer (score 2):

The charting controls are designed to present data that has been processeda and aggregated ready for presentation.

Sounds to me like you want a PieSeries to present a series that contains the Categories "VotedYes", "VotedNo", "Abstained" and "Did not vote" as its independent value and a vote count as the dependant value.  In that case you need to pass to the ItemsSource a collection containing this set of data, a single object will not do.

You will need to pass the VoteResult object through a function that returns something like `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>>`.

```cs
 public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>> ProcessVoteResult(VoteResult vr)
 {
      yield return new KeyValuePair<String, In232>("Voted Yes", vr.VotedYes);
      yield return new KeyValuePair<String, In232>("Voted No", vr.VotedNo);
      yield return new KeyValuePair<String, In232>("Abstained", vr.Abstained);
      yield return new KeyValuePair<String, In232>("Did Not Vote ", vr.DidntVote );
 }
```

Now you will probably want to bind the `VoteResult` since you appear to be using MVVM (from looking at your other questions).  You you will need a value converter:-

```cs
 public class VoteResultToEnumerableConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         if (value != null)
         {
              return ProcessVoteResult((VoteResult)value);
         }
         return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

You would then have this converter in a static resources somewhere above the chart:-

```
 <local:VoteResultToEnumerableConverter x:Key="vrconv" />
```

Then your chart would look like:-

```
 <toolkit:Chart>
     <toolkit:PieSeries
         ItemsSource="{Binding SomeVoteResult, Converter={StaticResource vrconv}}"
         DependentValuePath="Key"
         IndependendValuePath="Value"/>
 </toolkit:Chart>
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I was about to write a "surprisingly" similar answer ;) I just refreshed the page and found your answer, Kudos :)

Comment: Sorry - the explaination was ambiguous. Yes, your anwser looks like what I want. A collection of VoteResults with each VoteResult item having a pie chart.

Comment: To be more specific. I am using MVVM and I already have a VoteResults (collection) property in the viewmodel that the ItemsSource is binding to. My aim was to use this binding to supply data to the pie chart because the data is already in the VoteResult (singular) property.

Comment: How does the formatter: return ProcessVoteResult((VoteResult)value); access the IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>> ProcessVoteResult(VoteResult vr) in the viewmodel?